# Homology basis of minimal resolution

Tags: singularity-theory

Let $S$ be a compact algebraic surface with du Val singularities and $T$ be the minimal resolution of it. Is it true that 
$$
H_2(T,\mathbb{Z})/(\oplus_{i}\mathbb{Z}E_i)\cong H_2(S,\mathbb{Z}),
$$
where $E_i$s are the exceptional curves of the resolution? Or under what condition does it hold?

The claim is true for the local case. That is, let $G \subset SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ be a finite group and $X$ be the minimal resolution of $\mathbb{C}^2/G$. Then we have 
$$
H_2(X,\mathbb{Z})=\oplus_{i}\mathbb{Z}E_i
$$
where $E_i$s are again the exceptional curves of the resolution. In other words, $E_i$s form a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of $H_2(X,\mathbb{Z})$.

I think my problem is well-known and I would appreciate any help. I would also appreciate it if someone could teach me how other (co)homology groups change under minimal resolutions.

Comment: You mean $H_2(T,\mathbb{Z})=H_2(S,\mathbb{Z})\oplus(\oplus_{i}\mathbb{Z}E_i)
$. But how do you see $H_2(S,\mathbb{Z})$ into $H_2(T,\mathbb{Z})$? Don't you want to look at cohomology instead?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I fixed the problem. I would rather study homology of $S$. I think the Poince duality fails on $S$, so I use the quotient as above.

Comment: Did you try to write down Mayer Vietoris sequences for both $S$ and $T$ (choosing small tubular neighbourhoods of the exceptional fibers of the minimal resolution) ? It seems to me that it can work. I can add that the $H_1$ in unchanged ; in fact the $\pi_1$ itself is preserved for this kind of singularities (you can have a look at this post http://mathoverflow.net/questions/50580/comparing-fundamental-groups-of-a-complex-orbifolds-and-their-resolutions/50853#50853)

Comment: @Benoit I miscalculated the Mayer Vietoris sequences. You are right and it in particular works for $H_2$. Thanks!